# Implementation of std::rank for custom type (own class)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I tried to call std::rank on custom Foo type, it didn't work. 
I am guessing now that it works only on base type, and I need to extend class Foo to use it.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank suggests possible implementation.

I am still learning C++ and I don't have much experience with more advanced topics. 
Could you tell me how can I add std::rank to Foo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {   
};

    template<class T>
    struct Foo::rank : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

    template<class T>
    struct Foo::rank<T[]> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<T>::value + 1> {};

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    struct Foo::rank<T[N]> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<T>::value + 1> {};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1[5];
    Foo foo2[5][5];

    std::cout << std::rank<Foo>(foo1);
    std::cout << std::rank<Foo>(foo2);

}
```

> 8:22: error: qualified name does not name a class before ':' token
>   8:22: error: expected '{' before ':' token 8:22: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before ':' token 11:17: error: 'rank' is not a class
>   template 11:27: error: qualified name does not name a class before ':'
>   token 11:27: error: expected '{' before ':' token

Comment: When talking about something that went wrong, please include the compiler error or runtime error that you got, instead of saying "it didn't work".

Comment: @PabloOliva, you are right, sorry, I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do nothing with `std::rank`. All you need is to use `decltype`:

```
Foo foo1[5];
Foo foo2[5][5];

std::cout << std::rank<decltype(foo1)>{}; // 1
std::cout << std::rank<decltype(foo2)>{}; // 2
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/scRemH)